# How to install basic packages in case of absence of wireless kernel and no WLAN port in the laptop?

Tags: wifi, package-management, ethernet, realtek

I have recently installed `Kubuntu 20.04 LTS` https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/ on my laptop. However, the problem is that after installation I do not have a wireless module installed.

The wireless card on my laptop is Realtek `8821CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac`.
Corresponding to this driver is **rtl8821ce**.

In order to install it, one has to have a certain list of dependencies installed - namely `make`, `build-essential`, `dkms`, e.t.c. The problem is, that after installation I do not have even these basic packages.

The usual way to proceed in this case, which is frequently described on various forums, would be simply to connect to the WLAN cable, and type in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get update`

`apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

And then the required package would get the tree of dependences, which would be installed prior to the wireless module itself.

Unfortunalely, there is no WLAN port in my laptop, correspondingly, a way to connect to the `Ethernet`.
How to proceed in this case? I can look at the information of each package, presented at the https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/build-essential, and manually download all dependencies on the USB-stick. But, doing it by hand, checking the whole tree of requiered packages seems to be rather a formidable task (there are dozens of packages to be installed).

Is there some way, to get the package with all dependencies simulatenously?

Any help would be appreciated

**UPD**

The actual solution is straigntforward for experinced user. After installing the
Ubuntu I had no basic packages installed, so I ran :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

In order to get a `wl` driver one does:

```
lspci -v | grep Network
```

In order to establish the wireless card. Then, depending on the model, one can search through the web for the required modules. In my case, there is a `git` repo https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce, where all further instructions are given. Then one has to configure *Secure Boot* by entering password at least 8 characters long, and enter this password when rebooting.

Comment: Buy yourself a USB/ethernet connector, or a USB-c/ethernet one. They cost less than 20 bucks, Amazon must have a zillion or so of these.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Kubuntu on another PC **without** an active Internet connection
2. Run `sudo apt update`
3. Run `sudo apt install <what you need>`
4. Copy all the fetched packages from /var/cache/apt to a USB stick
5. On you laptop run `sudo apt install -f /media/flash/*deb`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've already resolved the issue with the help @MariusMatutiae . Nevertheless, it is a got idea